# Convert time_t to timeval

Tags: c, linux, gcc, time

I am facing problem in converting the `time_t` to `struct timeval`. I need the `tv_usec` & `tv_sec` value to be get populated from the `time_t` value.

In order to populate `tv_sec` and `tv_usec` we need to call `gettimeofday()`. But i dont want to call that function since i have time in `time_t`. From the `time_t` i want to extract/convert to milliseconds. Since existing code they use struct timeval for populating.

If you could suggest how to get millisecond from time_t would be great.

Any help on this would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not very clear (or very not clear). Add your code if you're actually expecting to get help.

Comment: Where the problem is? `time_t` is in seconds, `timeval` is a `struct` which includes also microseconds (so a simple cast to `int_32` for `tv_sec`  is enough). There isn't any offset issue (1/1/1970) between them so it should be straightforward. What's your problem, **exactly**?

Answer (score 8):

Definition of `struct timeval` (in `<sys/time.h>`) :

```
struct timeval 
{
     time_t      tv_sec;     /* seconds */
     suseconds_t tv_usec;    /* microseconds */
};
```

And as you can see, `time_t` can only hold **seconds**, you cannot get **milliseconds** from `time_t`. If you really want to work with a `timeval` object, you can simply define a `timeval` object, and manually add the `time_t` variable to it. i.e.,

```
time_t time_here; //Your time_t variable.
timeval time_now; //Your timeval object.
time_now.tv_sec = time_here; //Assign time_here to this object.
time_now.tv_usec = 0; //As time_t can hold only seconds.
```

Comment: Pedantic warning: `time_t` represents seconds in POSIX C, [but not in ISO C](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Time-Types.html).

Comment: Also, it turns out "but the OS-X should have the very same definitions of field names" is an [incorrect assumption](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/2/stat/). They seem to be stuck on a very old version of the standard.